# Other computer visible in Network, and can be accessed by IP, but not by name

Tags: networking

The title says it all pretty much.
I have a small network at home with 2 PCs that are both directly wired to my ISP's router via ethernet.

My computer A can see and access computer B's shared folders, but computer B can neither see nor access computer A's.

I looked this up on the internet and found out that i needed to turn on SMB1.0/CIFS Client on computer B. It partially solved the problem as i'm now able to see the other computer on the network as well as the router's hard drive (called Freebox).
I can access Freebox's hard drive by double clicking on it.
However, i can't access computer B's files by double clicking on it, it gives me the following error message : 
"Windows cannot access \Computer B. Check the spelling of the name. Otherwise, there might be a problem with your network. To try to identify and resolve network problems, click Diagnose."

I tried a few things :
ipconfig /dnsflush
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew

... as well as some other commands that i found in some articles / forums i don't remember.

A little help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It may be helpful to know what operating systems you are running.

Comment: Also, add the output of ipconfig/ifconfig to the question. Check the DNS of both computers and make sure they are pointing to the router and not google etc.

Answer (score 0):

I connected a 3rd computer to the network, a laptop. 
Strangely, computer B can see and access that laptop's files, but cannot access computer A's files. 
This makes me think that the problem might not come from computer B, but maybe from computer A...

Comment: Please delete this "answer" and edit your original question with this new information. SuperUser is not a traditional forum. Thank you. :)